# Thread is showing inconsistence result

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am creating 5 thread here using ThrdFunc. Here each thread update the listBox.

I was expecting message in this way. Initially come in this way but after some time

```
Thread1:Adding msg
Thread2:Adding msg
Thread3:Adding msg
```

But after some time I get message like

```
Thread0:Adding msg
Thread18967654:Adding msg
Thread18967654:Adding msg
Thread18967654:Adding msg
```

This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0;i<6;i++)
    {   
        nThreadNo = i+1;
        hWndProducer[i] = CreateThread(NULL,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)ProducerThrdFunc,(void*)&nThreadNo,0,&dwProducerThreadID[i]);     
        if (hWndProducer[i] == NULL) 
        {
           //ErrorHandler(TEXT("CreateThread"));
           ExitProcess(3);
        }
    }   

DWORD WINAPI    ThrdFunc ( LPVOID n )
{
    int *nThreadNo = (int*)n;       
    char chThreadNo[3];
    memset(chThreadNo,0,3);

    while(1)
    {
        itoa(*nThreadNo,chThreadNo,10);
        char* pMsg1 = new char[100];
        char* pMsg2 = new char[100];
        memset(pMsg1,0,100);
        memset(pMsg2,0,100);

        strcpy(pMsg1," Thread No:");        
        strcat(pMsg1,chThreadNo);
        strcat(pMsg1," Adding Msg:");

        PostMessage(stThreadInfoProd.hWndHandle,UWM_ONUPDATEPRODUCERLIST,(WPARAM)pMsg1,0);


    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the declaration of `nThreadNo`

Comment: nThreadNo is local to thread function.I am passing i value in thread which is received in nThreadNo inside ThreadFunc

Comment: No, we mean the definition of `nThreadNo` as used in the for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely `nThreadNo` is allocated on the stack. You're giving each thread a pointer to one of it's elements.

Once the function creating the threads returns, the array is no longer valid, but the thread functions are still pointing to it. The memory the threads are holding pointers to will most likely be overwritten, causing what was originally the thread ID to be overwritten with garbage.

Anything you pass another thread should generally be allocated on heap, either via `malloc` type functions or `new`, preferably `new` since this is C++.

For example, instead of `int nThreadNo[6]`, use `int* nThreadNo = new int[6]`. However, keep in mind that you will have to `delete[]` the memory `nThreadNo` points to when you're done with it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I can't be sure because you've not given all your code.

However, it looks like `nThreadNo` is a local variable, defined on the stack of the main thread.  You are passing the address of this variable to the threads, but you should be passing the value, or passing some heap allocated memory.

What you are doing is morally equivalent to returning from a function a pointer to a local variable, e.g.

```
int* foo()
{
    int i;
    return &i;
}
```

The simplest way to make your code behave is to make the following changes:

```
CreateThread(..., (void*)nThreadNo, ...

int nThreadNo = (int)n;
```

Answer (score 1):

nThreadNo has to be global because you are giving a pointer to it to your new thread.

Comment: CreateThread function is there in main thread.I am creating 5 thread using for loop and I am passing i(counter in for loop) in thread argumrnt.Is this wrong to pass the value.

Comment: If i make nThreadNo all thread will end up in same Thread No.since I passing this value for number the threading

Comment: you should call CreateThread not with a pointer to the thread-number but with the actual thread-number then, so "nThreadNo" instead of (void*)&nThreadNo. This is the solution, and to see the reason for this look at dauphic's post.

Comment: Of course you then dont use  int *nThreadNo = (int*)n; inside your thread-function but instead   int nThreadNo = n;